# Setting Realm Relationships

Tags: android, realm

I am integrating Realm but after some testing it seems that a relationship has to be set (and I assume managed) on both ends.

**Category.java**

```
private String name;
private RealmList<Subcategory> subcategories;
// Accessors not shown
```

**Subcategory.java**

```
private String name;
private Category category; 
// Accessors not shown
```

When I set category on a subcategory and then do a query, I can see the category I just set. However, if I then query the Category, I cannot see the subcategories.

Am I making a mistake or do I need to set a relationship on both ends? If I do, then I presume the removal of a relationship should also be done on both ends?

Comment: No, you don't need to do it in both ends. Show us how you're trying to retrieve the objects...

Comment: Using the generated accessors - `getSubcategories()`

Comment: try using `getSubcategories().first()` is it null?

Comment: getSubcategories returns an empty list.

Comment: probably is the way you are setting the subcategories... Can you show the code where you add the subcategories to the category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out relationships in Realm have to be set on both sides. It also means removing a relationship has to be done on both sides, adding significant complexity to our code. This is such a serious limitation when working with all but the simplest of database schemas that we wont be able to use Realm anymore.

Comment: Backlink is on our todo list and tracked here https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/607 . However, it needs some time to be well implemented in our underlying storage engine. Sorry for the inconvenience.